# :nth-child (or similar) formula to hide a div only if less than three child elements exist (needs to be CSS)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm not sure this is possible, though I've found some similar examples but they're not quite what I'm looking for (found on here and CSS Tricks).

I know `:only-child` exists, but it needs to be more like "only two children".

So what I have is the below, where I want to hide the third div `.controls` when only 1 `.child-item` exists.

```
<div>
  <div class="child-item">
  <div class="child-item">
  <div class="controls"> // Hide only if 1 child item exists
</div>
```

I know it's very easy in Javascript, but this is a short term fix on a site that will be getting an overhaul next year and I don't have access to the codebase, just a CMS where I can inject my own CSS.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: you can do `.controls:last-child:nth-child(2) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could hide the `.controls` element only if the previous sibling is both the `:first-child` and it has a `.child-item` class

```
.child-item:first-child + .controls {
   display: none
}
```

```css
  .child-item:first-child + .controls {
     display: none
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="child-item">child item 1</div>
  <div class="child-item">child item 2</div>
  <div class="controls">controls</div> <!-- visible -->
</div>

<hr />

<div>
  <div class="child-item">child item 1</div>
  <div class="controls">controls</div> <!-- not visible -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect and works exactly like what I needed - thanks a lot Fabrizio!